# Flutter Bluetooth giving error when app run in permission handling

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, flutter-build

*Pub get*

> The plugins `flutter_twitter_login` use a deprecated
> version of the Android embedding. To avoid unexpected runtime
> failures, or future build failures, try to see if these plugins
> support the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider  removing them
> since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
> If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the
> plugin to the V2 embedding:
> https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

**Run Console**

```
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-6.1.3\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\ServiceManager.java:152: warning: [deprecation] getDefaultAdapter() in BluetoothAdapter has been deprecated
        final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                                                                  ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 warning

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':permission_handler:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 37s
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting this command in the console to update to the latest version of the plugin
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions